# Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler

Tags: gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

What steps will reproduce the problem? and how i can solve this problem

1. IN Eclipse Indigo, right click on `project name --> google --> GWT Compile --> Compile`

I got error that says

> GWT compilation failed

In Eclipse console window, I got error message that says

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler

I am using windows 7 , eclipse juno 4.2 , and GWT sdk 2.5.1

During Gwt installation i left unchecked all app engine SDK options.
And also configure build path for jar files for projects i have.
but still this problem is coming .

---

Thanks for answering .                                                                        well I tried that before but nothing happened. Then I uninstall all all. And go to HELP--->Install new Software---> in text area i used this link  
  Google Update Site for Eclipse 4.2 - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 
                           then whenever i checked  Google Plugin for eclipse (required) and hit next it shows
  **Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42) requires 'org.objectweb.asm 0.0.0' but it could not be found**   
 i didn't understand what and where is the problem coming .

Answer (score 1):

I would double check your GWT install.  Right click on a project in eclipse, and select Properties.  Then under the Google option, click Web Toolkint.  On the panel to the right there should be an option "Use Google Web Toolkit".  Make sure that is checked.  Also Click "Configure SDKs", and ensure that the selected SDKs are indeed pointing to the correct file location. Finally, Make sure that your entry points are correctly added in the "Entry Point Modules" panel.

Comment: Thanks for answering .                                                                        well i tried that before but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar problem. I changed the proxy of my eclipse to manual and put in proxy settings for HTTP, HTTPs and port as 8080. This allowed the eclipse to connect to the network and download the required plugins. Try this out and let us know if it helps.